# Mongodb duplicate key error. How do i get the error field from the error object as object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When trying to enter a new document in mongo with a value on a field that already exist in another document i get this when i iterate through the error object:

```
for(var att in err){
    console.log(att+": "+err[att]);
}
```

name: MongoError
err: E11000 duplicate key error index: draw.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "spam@online.no" }
code: 11000
n: 0
ok: 1

So it tells me what i want to know, the problem is the email field. But can I get the offending field as a key/value rather than just a string?

Answer (score 5):

Using split on the error message returned work for me this way

```
var x= err.errmsg.split("index:")[1].split("dup key")[0].split("_")[0];
```

Comment: I added a `.trim()` because I had some space before the index name

Answer (score 4):

I use a regular expression. Like this

```
if(err){
   field = err.err.match(/\$(.*?)_/)[1]
}
```

Which is totally hacky but is working for me.

Comment: Does not work on compound indexes like this: `$client_1_email_1`

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of MongoDB, you can also do that.

Where `dupField` is a duplicate field name and `err.keyValue[dupField]` is a duplicate field value.

```
const handleDuplicateFieldsDB = err => {
    const dupField = Object.keys(err.keyValue)[0];
    return `Duplicate field(${dupField}). Please use another value(${err.keyValue[dupField]})!`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it collides, then making a find() for that query will return you the collision objects and you go from there.

Comment: You'd want to only do the find on indexed fields which were unique. It would require searching multiple fields potentially.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I'll guess I'll try findOne then before I do the save. Thought I could get away with using mongoError message. And I guess that should be possible in some way? The message tells me what I want, but as a string, that would be messy to do a regexp on I guess.

Comment: @oivind There'd still be a chance that the update would fail as another document could be saved between the call to `findOne` and the insert/update.

Comment: depends on the library you use, some give detailed errors, some just 1 or 0. I use native mongo lib but I don't think is any more detailed than yours.

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't give you the information that you are looking for :

> name: MongoError err: E11000 duplicate key error index: draw.users.$email_1 dup key: { : "spam@online.no" } code: 11000 n: 0 ok: 1

But it gives you enough to retrieve it.

You need to get the index that is causing the issue : "email_1" (use a regexp)

Then you need to ask the db about this index :

> draw.users.getIndexKey("email_1")